# Trying to webscrape multiple pdf files with Beautiful Soup: it downloads only a few pdf for no apparent reason

Tags: python, function, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape multiple pdf files from a web of a local council. I'm using a code I saw on YouTube, which I have tested in other pages where it works well. However, when I try it in the webpage I'm interested in, it downloads only a few pdfs and then the program stops. This webpage uses a year filter, which starts at 2022. However, when I run the program, only pdfs from 2007 are dowloaded for no apparent reasons. I cannot grasp whats happening.

Here is the code:

```
import os

def extract_url_pdf(input_url,folder_path=os.getcwd()):

    import os
    import requests
    from urllib.parse import urljoin
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import datetime

    url = input_url

    #If there is no such folder, the script will create one automatically
    folder_location = 'D:/Datos/Ordenanzas municipales/Municipalidad'
    if not os.path.exists(folder_location):os.mkdir(folder_location)

    response = requests.get(url)
    soup= BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser") 

    link_text=list()
    link_href=list()
    link_file=list()

    counter=0

    for link in soup.select("a[href$='.pdf']"):
         filename = os.path.join(folder_location,link['href'].split('/')[-1])
         with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
              f.write(requests.get(urljoin(url,link['href'])).content)
         link_text.append(str(link.text))
         link_href.append(link['href'])
         link_file.append(link['href'].split('/')[-1])
         counter+=1
         print(counter, "-Files Extracted from URL named ",link['href'].split('/')[-1])

extract_url_pdf(input_url="https://munihuamanga.gob.pe/normas-legales/ordenanzas-municipales/")
```

Comment: which year you are targeting ?

Comment: I started with 2022, but my plan was to download the pdf files for every year.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to download pdf. It's easiest and best to just download them from the repository on the site. Just specify year in function

```
def download_pdf(year):
    url = f'https://munihuamanga.gob.pe/Documentos_mph/Munitransparencia/Normas_legales/Ordenanzas_municipales/{year}/'
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    for filename in [href.get('href') for href in soup.find_all('a') if '.pdf' in href.get('href')]:
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(requests.get(url + filename).content)
            print(f'{filename} was loaded')


download_pdf(2022)
```

OUTPUT:

```
o_m_01_emitido_17022022.pdf was downloaded
o_m_02_emitido_08032022.pdf was downloaded
o_m_03_emitido_04042022.pdf was downloaded
o_m_04_emitido_04042022.pdf was downloaded
o_m_04_emitido_04042022p.pdf was downloaded
o_m_05_emitido_08042022.pdf was downloaded
o_m_06_emitido_13042022.pdf was downloaded
o_m_07_emitido_13052022.pdf was downloaded
```